# FB Graph API Page Message Post Issue

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have this very confusing and weird issue with the FB Graph API. I own multiple FB Pages, and using Webhook and FB Messanger API to post Message to FB Page.
Now WebHook is working fine and I am getting all the messages to my server.

However, when I am replying back to FB Page Message, I am getting **Bad Request 400** error.
Now the confusing part is I am not getting this issue everytime. Its happening with few Chats within each page.
For Example: I have Page 1, Page 2 and Page 3
Now, If User P1 connects with me on Page 1, I am able to send replies, but when some other user, let's say User P2 connects on same page, I am unable to reply and getting above said error.
Same is happening with almost each of the pages. I can reply to few users, and not to others. Using same code throughout all the pages, with different **AccessTokens** for each page.

Below is my code:

```
private static string PostRaw(string url, string data)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "POST";
            using (var requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                requestWriter.Write(data);
            }

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("GetResponse returns null");

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                return sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

protected string sendGenericMessage()
        {

            var messageData = $@" {{recipient: {{  ""id"": ""xxxxxxxxxxx""}},""message"": {{""text"": ""Thanks for sending message so fast, yes we have got your message. And this is a test reply from within the integrated app."" }}}}";
            return PostRaw("https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/me/messages?access_token=ACCESSTOKENxxxx", messageData);
        }
```

Below is the error I am getting in Response Header:
Now my account is working fine as same page is working with other chats.

Status: ProtocolError

Status Code: 400 Bad Request

Response: {"error":{"message":"(#2022) Your account is temporarily unavailable. Regain access by logging in from a mobile or web browser.","type":"OAuthException","code":2022,"fbtrace_id":"Ab0+9Dhagz3"}}

Comment: Not yet, and seems no other member is able to fix it too :(

Comment: @GarthSebastian Have you found any solution? I randomly get it for some messages and don't get for the others...

Comment: The issue resolved itself. I was so frustrated with this and planned to wait for a while to fix it, however, now its fixed on its own, dont know what caused the issue, and dont know what fixed him.

Comment: Seems like internal bug from Facebook